# No warning when using nonnull?

Tags: objective-c, nullable, non-nullable

With code like this:

```
- (nonnull NSString *)testing {
    return nil;
}
```

Shouldn't I get a compiler warning? I get no warning all, which seems to make the entire nullability stuff seem useless?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my opinion it should produce a warning, but I couldn't figure out to get one either.

What might be helpful though, is using `Product > Analyze` to run the CLANG Static Analyzer. This should give the following hint:

> Null is returned from a method that is expected to return a non-null value

Another thing worth mentioning is the setting `CLANG_WARN_NULLABLE_TO_NONNULL_CONVERSION` which is named `Incorrect Uses of Nullable values` in the `Apple LLVM 7.1 - Warnings - All languages` section of the Build Settings.

This setting will not produce a warning for incorrect return values, but it shows a warning when using the method with incorrect parameters (e.g. nil for nonnull parameters).

This answer refers to Xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014)

Answer (score 0):

"nonnull" is mostly there to combine Objective-C and Swift. Swift will translate the type of the method to "NSString" and not "NSString?".

Comment: Right, but even when not using Swift at all, it should still be used right? The compiler does use the hints in some other places, like setting a nonnill property explicitly to nil. But in this case, no warning at all. Seems weird.